# How do I add a submenu to the top of a Custom Post Type menu?

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, submenu

I'm trying to make the admin area of a website easier for a client to use. To do this, I've created some custom submenu pages to order a long list of custom posts. However, I would like one of these submenu pages to be the top-level submenu page, and for it to be the default page that becomes active when the Custom Post Menu is clicked.

```
add_submenu_page( 'edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan', 'Online Workout Plans', 'Home', 'edit_posts', 'home', 'online_plans_admin_home' );

add_action( 'admin_menu', 'online_plans_add_sub_pages' );
?>

<?php // Reorder Submenu
function my_submenu_order($menu_ord) {
  global $submenu;

  $arr = array();
  $arr[] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan'][16];
  $arr[] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan'][5];
  $arr[] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan'][10];
  $arr[] = $submenu['edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan'][15];
  $submenu['edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan'] = $arr;

  return $menu_ord;
}

add_filter('custom_menu_order', 'my_submenu_order');

?>
```

When I apply the code, the Custom Post Type menu link changes from "edit.php?post_type=online_workout_plan" to "admin.php?page=home". I have tried playing around with the url when adding the submenu page but to no avail.

Is there something I need to do to update the admin-url as I make the custom submenu page the top-level page in the menu?

Any help much appreciated.